# Default Date Formatting in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, isodate

I am currently debugging a scenario in which dates need to be read from a string in a stored procedure.

The code that we have used is a simple convert statement.
e.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @dateInput)
```

The problem comes when I need to test the dates coming from the Chinese date format (yyyy.mm.dd) which is ISO 102.

What settings in Windows 10 / SQL Server must be set so that running  `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020.05.16')`  will not return
*"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."*

I understand that using `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020.05.16', 102)` would work but that would make the universal stored procedure incorrect when running with different windows date formats

Comment: Your problem is passing your date as a string parameter - and then writing code that is subject to settings that can be changed. Quite simply - don't do that. Your parameter should be defined as a date and the calling code should supply it as such - presumably this is an application.

Comment: @SMor while I agree the current application method is not the best, these settings are managed by Database Administrators and are made for this exact purpose, not user defined settings that are subject to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with changing my windows settings to reflect the same date format I also changed:

- My default language of my SQLEXPRESS server in *Properties > Advanced > Default Language*
- My default language of my SQL User Login *Properties > General > Default Language*

This meant that it could read the direct string value without needed the ISO 102 identifier.

Comment: It is not, however, asking a valid question, and providing a valid answer *is* more than welcome, as the OP might have done here, @SMor . Asking and answering your own questions is encouraged. [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) Though I am not sure if this *is* an answer.

Comment: This is the answer, as I was typing out the question I was going through settings to narrow down the problem and found these. I thought it more useful to post with an answer since I could not find an answer online to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If the input value is always in the format `yyyy.MM.dd` then use the appropriate style code (don't rely on the language setting of the `LOGIN`):

```sql
DECLARE @StringInput varchar(10) = '2020.05.16';
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,@StringInput,102);
```

Ideally, however, instead of defining your parameter as a `varchar` define it as a `datetime` in the first place and have the application pass the correct data type; not a string. But that is a different question for the language your application is written in.

Comment: Unfortunately the input value will not always be the same format, based on the user's settings, The current solution works given the environment is set up correctly, I agree with the datetime input being the better solution but I am not the lead developer of the application.

Comment: *"Unfortunately the input value will not always be the same format"* Then that leaves the latter statement as the solution, @JaredWare . That's what you **need** to do. Otherwise, if you can't get a consistent value from the application, you would have no idea what value a string could mean. For example What would `'20-11-12'` mean? 20 November 2012? 12 November 2020? 11th of the 20th month in 2012? 20 November 1912? Fix the application.